# What does the index operator do to arbitrary pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Suppose we have

```
int x = 4;
int *ptr = &x;
```

I was hoping that `ptr[0]` would be `ptr`, `ptr[1]` would be `ptr + 1`, etc. However, something completely different happens. I ran

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 4;
    int* ptr;
    ptr = &x;

    //ptr vs ptr[0]
    printf("ptr: %p\n\n", ptr);
    printf("ptr[0]: %p\n\n", ptr[0]);

    //ptr + 1 vs ptr[1]
    printf("ptr + 1: %p\n\n", ptr + 1);
    printf("ptr[1]: %p\n\n", ptr[1]);

    //ptr + 5 vs ptr[5]
    printf("ptr + 5: %p\n\n", ptr + 5);
    printf("ptr[5]: %p\n\n", ptr[5]);
}
```

The result was

```
ptr: 0115FBF4

ptr[0]: 00000004

ptr + 1: 0115FBF8

ptr[1]: CCCCCCCC

ptr + 5: 0115FC08

ptr[5]: 00000001
```

Comment: If you had done `ptr` vs. `&ptr[0]`, `&ptr[1]`, `&ptr[5]`, etc., you would have seen something more like you probably expected.

Comment: @SteveSummit Than you for the thought-provoking comment. I ran it and I see that `ptr + 1` is the same as `&ptr[1]`. But this introduces another confusion for me. `ptr[1]` is just the content of the 4 contiguous bytes starting at address `ptr + 1`. So I would expect that doing `&ptr[1]` is the same as doing something like `&6`, which results in an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ptr[0]` is `*(ptr + 0)`, `ptr[1]` is `*(ptr + 1)`, etc. Indexing computes the offset *and dereferences*. You should have gotten a warning about using `%p` to print something that isn't a pointer.

Comment: That you that makes a lot of sense. I just noticed that I did get warnings. Usually when I don't get errors I become happy and don't look at anything else haha.

Comment: @user56202 To reduce any undue happiness, compile with `-Werror` when using gcc or clang, or compile with `/WX` when using microsoft's compiler. [More here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/)

Comment: @user3386109 Yes indeed, I should really start paying attention to the warnings.